# Does [Aptana] have a minimize function, if so where is it?

Tags: optimization, aptana3

I am working in Aptana Studio three and am wondering if there is a quick easy way to minimise your code when finished developing?

Say you have a long SQL insert that you have separated out over several lines for ease of editing during development.  At production time, you could go through and remove all your line breaks to compress the code into less lines but this could be a very time consuming manual task.

Just wondering if there is an easier way?

Comment: Generally putting code onto fewer lines doesn't actually give any benefit apart from when this code must be transferred over a network (e.g. to a web browser) in which case you save a few bytes of network traffic. I doubt it will actually give you any benefit to do this.

Comment: Hi Richard,  Thanks.  I often wondered if it was worth the hassle. If you'd like to put that as an answer I can accept it if no-one actually has a quick and easy method in Aptana.

Comment: Have posted a modified version of my comment as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether Aptana has this feature but I doubt it will give you any benefit to do this.

Generally putting code onto fewer lines doesn't actually give any benefit apart from when this code must be transferred over a network (e.g. to a web browser) in which case you save a few bytes of network traffic.